# Unable to share autowired objects in groovy tests

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, autowired, spock, shared

I have an annoying problem when I want to test my SpringBoot app with groovy spock.

I want to autowire a bean in my spock, and this works fine.

I want to use this bean in a test in "setupSpec" then there is a problem that I can only use @Shared objects in "setupSpec".

When I add the @Shared annotation next to @Autowired for that bean, the test cannot be started.

Looks like @Autowired and @Shared does not work together.

What is the workaround? This is very annoying, I also found this site where there is no answer:
https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/267

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in Spock 2.0 see the [docs](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_shared_fields_injection).

> Due to certain limitations, injection into shared fields is not enabled by default but can be opted-in to. Refer to javadoc of `org.spockframework.spring.EnableSharedInjection` for further information.